# How to give user a option to choose Login or Signup in python using django framework?

Tags: python, django, web-applications, pycharm

**Hello**
I am creating a web app and I want to give usera option to login or signup using django . But the code was not giving the output I want . If Signin is choosen , the user will be redirected to his feed . If Signup is chosen , he need to create a new account using his email . 
**I just Used This Code :**

```
import django
import datetime
def getdate(m,d,y):
    m=int(input("Enter Month :"))
    d=int(input("Enter Date  :"))
    y=int(input("Enter Year  :"))
    date1=datetime.date(m,d,y)
    return date1
print("WELCOME TO MOVIE REVIEW")
asksgn=print("I Want To Sign In ")
asksgnup=print("I Need To Create A Account ")
sgn=input(asksgn)
sgnup=input(asksgnup)
if sgnup==True:
    class usrprofile:
        usrname,__pwd,dob,nick=0
        def profile (self,usrname,__pwd,dob,nick):
            self.usrname=input("Enter Your Name :")
            self.__pwd=input("Enter Your Password :")
            self.dob=getdate()
            self.nick=input("Enter Your Nickname :")
        def __init__(self):
            print("Welcome To Movie Review Office")
        def __del__():
            print("Bye Bye")
```

Answer (score 0):

Django has inbuilt login, logout and authenticate methods to help developers with authentication.

Documentation for the authenciation using Django : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/

Signing up users is same as creating a new Django entry through the Django ORM.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
def signup(request):
    username = "example"
    password = "example"
    user = User.objects.create(username=username, password=password)
```